# Local New-PSSession fails in official powershell linux based docker images

Tags: powershell, docker, ubuntu, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

Running powershell core using docker (official microsoft images),
I am trying to set up a local session in my script so I can later execute code in that session.

I have tried using the following Linux Images:

```
6.2.3-alpine-3.8
6.2.3-centos-7
6.2.3-debian-9
6.2.3-ubuntu-18.04
```

In both alpine and debian I am getting error: 
`This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.`

In both Centos & Ubuntu I am getting error:
`MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED`

I tried digging the error but it was only mentioned in cases of trying to remote from linux to windows, while here all I am trying to do is open the most basic local session.

```bsh
        $FullCommand = "Invoke-Expression $CompleteScript"
        $Session = New-PSSession
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($FullCommand)
        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

or

```bsh
        $Session = New-PSSession
        Invoke-Expression -Session $Session -Command $CompleteScript
```

Before even moving on to remote sessions from linux to windows I would like to establish a local session and be able to execute code on it.

I am new to powershell so might be missing something, but I expected local session to work on at least one of microsoft's official docker images of powershell core, the documentation there didn't give me any insight on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following dockerfile snippet to install WSMan, as proposed [here](https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2020/08/21/wacky-wsman-on-linux/).

```
#install powershell WSMan.Management module 
RUN pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name PSWSMan -Force"
RUN pwsh -Command "Install-WSMan"
```